# How to parse a duration with format P0Y0M0D

Tags: php

I am working on a webservice returning an xml file that formats durations this way:

```
P0Y0M0DT5H50M0.000S
```

In the example above, it means the duration is 5 hours and 50 minutes

Does a php function exist that can read this time format or convert it into a timestamp? 
I tried with strtotime() and the DateTime object but it either returned false or a fatal error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex match for this, assuming your pattern is consistent:

```
$timestamp = 'P0Y0M0DT5H50M0.000S';
preg_match('~T(?P<Hours>\d{1,2})H(?P<Minutes>\d{1,2})M(?P<Seconds>\d{1}\.\d{3})S~', $timestamp, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[Example:](https://eval.in/463333)

```
Array
(
    [0] => T5H50M0.000S
    [Hours] => 5
    [1] => 5
    [Minutes] => 50
    [2] => 50
    [Seconds] => 0.000
    [3] => 0.000
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I came upon this question and the PHP [DateInterval class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for parsing ISO intervals hadn't been mentioned yet. It doesn't support fractional seconds like in the example, but otherwise it can parse this just fine:

```
new DateInterval( 'P0Y0M0DT5H50M0S' )
```

gives this result:

```
    class DateInterval#2425 (15) {
      public $y =>
      int(0)
      public $m =>
      int(0)
      public $d =>
      int(0)
      public $h =>
      int(5)
      public $i =>
      int(50)
      public $s =>
      int(0)
      public $weekday =>
      int(0)
      public $weekday_behavior =>
      int(0)
      public $first_last_day_of =>
      int(0)
      public $invert =>
      int(0)
      public $days =>
      bool(false)
      public $special_type =>
      int(0)
      public $special_amount =>
      int(0)
      public $have_weekday_relative =>
      int(0)
      public $have_special_relative =>
      int(0)
```

Comment: If the duration includes split seconds, you can still instantiate DateInterval with:  `preg_replace('/\.(\d{3})S$/', 'S', $P0Y0M0D_string)`